# Blazor Session Storage

Tags: session, blazor, blazor-server-side, session-storage

At my current project(blazor server side) I want to start using the session storage for user data like roles and names.
I've tried Blazored.SessionStorage and AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage.
The problem I'm facing is, that I just can't get the value(it's always null) and I don't know why.
Code I'm using:

```
public void GetUserInfo()
{
    var x = sessionStorage.GetAsync<string>("Name");
    var y = sessionStorage.GetAsync<string>("Email");
    string Name = x.ToString();
    string Email = y.ToString();
}
```

And

```
[Inject] public ProtectedSessionStorage sessionStorage { get; set; }
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    string Name = Helper.Name;
    string Email = Helper.Email;
    await sessionStorage.SetAsync("Name", Name);
    await sessionStorage.SetAsync("Email", Email);

    var x = sessionStorage.GetAsync<string>("Name");
    var y = sessionStorage.GetAsync<string>("Email");
    Name = x.Result.Value;
    Email = y.Result.Value;
}
```

Thanks to everyone in advance and have a great day! :)

Comment: Which `render-mode` are you using ?

Comment: Go to `_Host.cshtml` and check that ?

Comment: I've tried render-mode "Server" and "ServerPrerendered".

Comment: I see `GetUserInfo()`  and `OnAfterRenderAsync` are `async` but without `awiat`  try to add `await`. Please surround your code in `OnAfterRenderAsync` with `if (firstRender)`

Comment: Is there anyway you can still use the ServerPrerendered option? Because without it my nav bar doesnt load.

Comment: Why don't you use Dependency Injection and store this in memory?

Comment: Because we use terminalservers and users on the same ip(server) get the same data. So if a user logs in after someone already logged in (on the same server) the first user gets the data from the second user because the data gets updated.

Comment: @P__, that's why you have different service types. A scoped server type is unique per request (per user). I've added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### DO NOT USE THIS SOLUTION AS IS. WHEN I GET THE TIME I WILL UPDATE IT TO A WORKING SOLUTION

I suggest adding this as an injected object using Dependency Injection.

Create a class to hold this information and add is as a Scoped service.

Class:

```
public class UserInfo : IUserInfo //Create an interface
{
    public static Name { get; set; }
    public static Email { get; set; }
}
```

Injection (Program.cs on .NET 6):

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    //For WSAM
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    //For Server
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    ...
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserInfo, UserInfo>(); //Scoped Service injection
}
```

Add data to injected service:

```
[Inject]
public IUserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }

protected override void OnInitialized() //Use whatever Life Cycle methods works for your implementation
{
    UserInfo.Name = Helper.Name;
    UserInfo.Email = Helper.Email;
}
```

Usage example:

```
@inject IUserInfo UserInfo
@page "/"

<div>@UserInfo.Name</div>
<div>@UserInfo.Email</div>
```

Comment: That looks very interesting and pomising. Sadly I dont have the time to test it today. But I'm definitly gonna try it in the next few weeks. Thanks! :)

Comment: This will not persist over different tabs though

Comment: @AlexHall, this is server side and will persist. For WASM a different solution is required.

Comment: Scoped services do not persist over multiple tabs https://blazor-university.com/dependency-injection/dependency-lifetimes-and-scopes/scoped-dependencies/

Comment: @AlexHall, try testing it first. I just did a test and the scoped service persisted.

Comment: Already tested. Try again. It doesn't persist

Comment: @AlexHall, please send Blazor Fiddle. You are sure you're using server side, and not WASM?

Comment: this is 100% Blazor Server